# Put multiple PHP arrays inside another array maintaining keys including duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

If I have two arrays and I want to "combine" them into one array whilst maintaining each individual array and leaving the keys as they are as they are always duplicated each iteration, can I do this?:

```
$array1 = array('0'=>'Bob', '1'=>'Tom', '2'=>'John');
$array2 = array('0'=>'Michelle', '1'=>'Joan', '2'=>'Susan');
```

If I use array_merge:

```
$new_array = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

I get:

```
array('0'=>'Bob','1'=>'Tom','2'=>'John','3'=>'Michelle','4'=>'Joan','5'=>'Susan')
```

whereas I want to get something like:

```
array(array('0'=>'Bob', '1'=>'Tom', '2'=>'John'),array('0'=>'Michelle', '1'=>'Joan', '2'=>'Susan'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new array and add the other arrays to that one like this:

$arr = array($array1, $array2);

Answer (score 1):

$ new_array = array ($ array, $ array2);